# List turns to "None", trying to make a factorizing program

Tags: python, list, math, factorization

I am trying to make a program that factorized numbers. I made a definition for making prime numbers, it worked fine, but when I try the factorization it doesn't work. I think the prime list turns to None. Here's the code:

```
def prime_num(ulist):
    list_primes = sorted(ulist)
    num = list_primes[-1]
    i = 0
    while i < 1:
        num += 1
        count = 0
        while i < 1:
            prime = True
            if count >= len(list_primes):
                count -= 1
                break
            if num/list_primes[count] == int(num/list_primes[count]):
                prime = False
                break
            count += 1
        if prime:
            return num


def factorize(num):
    prime_list = [2, 3]
    factors_list = []
    i = 0
    while i <= round(num/2):
        if int(num/prime_list[i]) == num/prime_list[i]:
            i = 0
            factors_list = factors_list.append(prime_list[i])
            num /= prime_list[i]
        random_list = prime_list.append(prime_num(prime_list))
        prime_list = random_list
        i += 1
        print(factors_list)


factorize(6)
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work" more clearly. Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

`list.append()` modifies the list, then returns None

When you use `factors_list = factors_list.append(prime_list[i])`, you append `prime_list[i]`, then you affect None over the changed list.